# Is there a standard namespace for local definitions of multi-key characters in the ~/.XCompose file?

Tags: namespace, compose-key

I want to add some personal definitions to my ~/.XCompose file, but I don't want them to conflict with any official definitions (especially those that appear in the future and aren't defined yet).

Is there a special leading string (or other method) of providing a reserved namespace for private use?

I see that in `/usr/share/X11/locale/en_US.UTF-8/Compose`, the following characters never appear immediately after a "Multi_key":

```
@   }   $   &
```

so they would be potential candidates.

And perhaps more convenient, would be to simply repeat the compose button:

```
<Multi_key> <Multi_key> …
```

But before I invent my own standard for a local namespace, I'd like to know for sure that there isn't already one.

Comment: Good question.  I would be surprised if they (whoever get the compose mappings into trunk) have thought so far ahead as to have reserved namespaces for private use.